C++Builder FMX TPrintDialog->Copies does not change after executing dialog at runtime
When I try to enter the number of copies in the PrintDialog window, the PrintDialog->Copies property does not change. That is, I am trying to write the value of the PrintDialog->Copies property to a variable, but I always get the initial value of the property which was set at design-time.
For example, the value of the Copies property is 10 at design-time. I entered 4 in the Copies field of the PrintDialog window at runtime.
My code:
if (!PrintDialog1->Execute()) return;

int cnt = PrintDialog1->Copies;
ShowMessage(IntToStr(cnt));

The message always shows me 10. Always.
IDE: Embarcadero C++Builder 10.4.
OS: Windows 7 x64.
Interestingly, the same code in Delphi works as it should! Please help me to resolve this issue.

C++Builder and Delphi share common frameworks and underlying platform APIs. It should not be possible for FMX to behave differently between C++ and Pascal projects as you claim.

What you describe was a bug in FMX in 10.1-10.4:
RSP-16274: TPrintDialog.Copies: property value doesn't set in the print dialog
TPrintDialog.DoExecute() in FMX.Printer.pas calls IFMXDialogService.DialogPrint(), and the underlying problem was that the TFMXDialogService.DialogPrint() implementation in FMX.Dialogs.Win.pas did not read out the updated Copies value from the Win32 API after the dialog is closed.
This was fixed in 10.4 Release 1, so make sure you have all of the available updates installed.
If upgrading is not an option, you have 2 options:

make a copy of FMX.Dialogs.Win.pas, patch it manually to fix the bug, and then add that copy to your project.

write your own class that implements IFMXDialogService.DialogPrint() to call the Win32 API yourself, and then use TPlatformServices.RemovePlatformService() and  TPlatformServices.AddPlatformService() to remove the default class and register your class at program startup.



Remy, many thanks to you! It really looks like a bug... I'll try to upgrade IDE.
